# Pass a function reference as callback to my service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to refactor my code to avoid DRY and found that I'm doing the same stuff in two callback functions from my $resource. But I haven't managed to pass in a reference to a function instead of the function declaration itself.

I'm trying this:

```
emailService.getEmails(people, function(data) {
    data.foo();
});
```

But i want something like this:

```
emailService.getEmails(people, $scope.callback);

$scope.callback = function(data) {
    data.foo();
};
```

I don't seem to get it to work. Can I do this even?

Comment: You need to declare `$scope.callback` before the `emailService.getEmails` line.  Is `$scope` declared anywhere?

Comment: As a sidenote, you shouldn't avoid DRY - in fact, you should be as DRY as possible; it's WET that's dangerous. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s because `$scope.callback` isn’t defined (yet) when you run the `emailService.getEmails` function. You can change it to:

```
emailService.getEmails(people, callback);

function callback(data) {
    data.foo();
};
```

Comment: Function declared like that will be "hoisted" to the top of their scope.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that about the "hoisting" =)